# Where to copy ITelephony.java in android studio and how to import it? Please don't close this without answering

Tags: java, android, telephony, telephonymanager

I have looked at other SO questions similar to mine. But i could not find any help.
I have copied ITelephony.java to com/android/internal/telephony. when i tried to use the same it says "Cannot resolve symbol ITelephony".

```
private ITelephony telephonyService;
```

Can any one please point me in the right direction.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a package under java folder

```
com.android.internal.telephony
```

and then copy `ITelephone` interface in that package

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;


public interface ITelephony {

    boolean endCall();

    void answerRingingCall();

    void silenceRinger();
}
```

Comment: thanks Murali please upvote it too so other people can see and implement that solution :)

Comment: How to accept the call by using this interface ? How can I implement the the same ?

Answer (score 0):

In my project the file is **ITelephony.aidl** (not .java) as it is an interface to system calls that we are not allowed direct access to.

Contents:

> package com.android.internal.telephony;
>
> ```
> interface ITelephony {
>
>      void answerRingingCall();
>
>      boolean endCall();
>
>      void silenceRinger();
>
>      boolean showCallScreenWithDialpad(boolean showDialpad); 
> }
> ```